# Glide returns empty or null Drawable / Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-glide, android-bitmap

I am trying to get an image from a URL through Glide without loading it into an ImageView but using it for another purpose instead.
When I do try to load it into an image view - `Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView)` - it works.
But when I use something with a `onResourceReady` callback for instance, the `resource` parameter is always empty or null. I call it empty because when I debug it it displays it as `""` in the studio and also has its fields set to null or 0, and cannot be loaded as an image.
I tried with a `RequestListener<R>`, with a `SimpleTarget<Bitmap>`, with a `CustomTarget<T>`, and with `.get()` (for Bitmap and Drawable) but none worked.
Here is some sample Kotlin code:

```
// First attempt
Glide.with(context).load(url).addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?,model: Any?,target: Target<Drawable>?,isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean { }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                // resource is empty here
            }
}).submit()

// Second attempt
Glide.with(context).load(url).submit().get() // returns an empty Drawable

// Third attempt
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(url).submit().get() // returns an empty Bitmap

// Fourth attempt
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(url).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap> {
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}

        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            // resource is empty here
        }
}

// Fifth attempt (deprecated)
object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            // resource is empty here
    }
}
```

Maybe I tried some other things but nothing worked.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You are seeing resource = "" but resource not null. use imageView.setImageBitmap(resource) and you can see the image

Comment: You're right. Thanks! :) Seems like I was making a mistake somewhere else but thought it was the Bitmap because of `resource=""`.

Comment: What was the solution?